# Building an Azure Application Gateway with SSL termination using PowerShell - Can anyone get this to work? Listener SSL resource reference error

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-powershell, azure-application-gateway

Trying to build an Azure Application Gateway using the following instructions and cannot get it to build without an exception stating that the certificate referenced by the listener cannot be found

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ssl-powershell

Can anyone get this to work?

I have tried following the instructions verbatim and it will not work.  I can build an Application Gateway without SSL, but not with SSL as described in Microsoft's TLS Termination How-To guide.

Comment: When you run 'New-AzApplicationGatewaySslCertificate' with the parameters, try seeing what the variable's value is.  For PowerShell when a 'New-' command fails it's often empty when you try to refer to it.  It's possible the command failed because the PFX password was incorrect or the cert data was malformed.

Comment: @DusDee, Thank you for responding.  I figured out late last night before seeing this that my certificate was the issue.  The exception message was throwing me off and I had been staring at my screen too long lol.  Thanks again!  I am going to consider your comment as the answer.

Comment: Awesome! I'll add an answer for visibility as well if you'd like.  I commented because I wasn't 100% sure it'd be the cause but I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

@DusDee had the best advice on debugging this!  This is now working and integrated with the rest of my scripts.  Check the certificate data and make sure it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

The error experienced was because when running `New-AzApplicationGatewaySslCertificate`, this command can fail for a few reasons:

- Incorrect PFX password
- Invalid certificate data

If you assigned this to a variable called `$sslCert`, trying to evaluate its value when the command fails will return an empty result which is both 'falsey' and not a `PSApplicationGatewaySslCertificate` object which is what the `New-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListener` command requires when configuring an HTTPS listener.

This causes the deployment to fail because the listener is referencing a non-existant certificate since it was passed as an empty variable.